# Dense subset of $L^p[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

It is true that $C_{0}^{\infty}[a,b]$,  (the space of all smooth functions f with the property that f and all its derivatives vanish at a and b) is dense in $L^p[a,b]$ with $1\leq p< \infty$ ?

How do I prove it? I know that $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L_{p}(\mathbb{R})$ with $1\leq p< \infty$, but I don't know if this can help me.

Comment: (1) Yes. (2) given a function in $L^p[a,b]$, extend it by zero outside. You get a function in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Next you play with a cut-off of your original function.

Comment: But how do I get a function in $C_{0}^{\infty}[a,b]$, does a bump function work?@user225318

Comment: You could even get by with the subset of functions of the form $p(x)e^{-1/[(x-a)(b-x)]}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial function.

Comment: @JonasMeyer , could you please give me a little more details?

Comment: @David: have you tried playing around with the transitivity of density relations, e.g., if A is dense on B and B is dense in C, then A is dense in C. You know con. functions with compact support are dense in simple functions, which are dense in $L^p[a,b]$. And remember Weirstrass' approximation theorem.